# How to check if an HTTPS URL redirects to an HTTP URL?

Tags: http, redirect, web, httpurlconnection

I have a list of HTTPS URLs and I want to make sure they are accessible. I use HttpURLConnection to follow redirects by checking for any 300/301/302 responses, following the redirect, and so on until I get a 200 or anything else.

How do I check along the way that none of the redirects are to a HTTP (non-secure) endpoint?

Does it ever fail if the redirect from an HTTPS goes to HTTP, or do I have to manually check?

Comment: By checking the first five characters of the URL you get redirected to?

Comment: You're using Java I assume?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpURLConnection` won't follow redirects when switching protocol (http -> https, https -> http). So you'll know when such redirects happen. If you want to be 100% safe, call

- `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false)` or
- `conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)`.